# Problem with my first MySQL Function. Getting one error after the other

Tags: mysql, function

So, I'm making my first MySQL function.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE ID INT;  
SELECT
    LandID INTO ID
FROM
    Landen
WHERE
    Landnaam = landnaam;
RETURN ID;
END
```

The parameter is a varchar.
So, let's say I got a record in `Landen` with the `Landnaam` 'Nederland'.

I run my function, give 'Nederland' as parameter.
But then it gives me to following error:

1172 - result consisted of more than one row

Which makes no sense at all. Cause when I give something as a parameter that is not in my database, like 'ASDASD', I get the same error.
And when limmiting the results with

```
LIMIT 1
```

It just always returns 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If landnaam is a varchar, you have to pass it as it. That means : WHERE Landnaam = 'landnaam'

Comment: I did that, then it just returns null, whatever I type in. And yes, I'm really sure that the things I try as parameter are in the Database.

Comment: remove the where clause and try it

Comment: That would ruin the whole purpose of the function. Since I want to get the ID of the parameter. But yea, than I get the 1172 error again.

Comment: ohh I think I got it. You're trying to store into the ID var, more than 1 row. That's impossible, so the where filtering is selecting more than 1 row. So, more than 1 row in the Landen table contains in the Landnaam field, the landnaam word. Try adding more conditions to your where clause so it returns only 1 row

Comment: Yea, tried that, but, the strange thing is, I only have 3 records in my `Landen` table.
1 - Nederland
2 - Duitsland
3 - Belgie

That's it. So I can't really add more conditions..

Comment: if the record is nederland, why are you asking for 'landnaam' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop function if exists myfunc;
delimiter //
create function myfunc(str varchar(50))
returns int
reads sql data
begin
declare id int;  
select landid into id from Landen where landnaam = str limit 1;
return id;
end//
delimiter ;

select myfunc('nederland');
```

Comment: I don't know what in this query is different than mine, but it works. Limit just gave me 1 when I tried it, whatever I gave as parameter. Anyway, thank you very much, I can continue with it now :)

Comment: Done :) Sorry, first time I ever posted anything here :P

Comment: No problem. I told you because you are a new user and I've supposed you don't know about it as often it occurs. Thanks :)